Is Ukraine considering restoring nuclear weapons?
On a pro-Ukrainian Reddit thread I came across a post claiming that Ukraine is claiming that it can restore nuclear weapons in a couple of weeks, and will consider it.
It followed through to this page Ukrainian authorities consider restoring nuclear arsenal which links to Selenskyj rudert nach Atom-Aussage zurück which I believe is in German so I've no way to verify (I'm also not sure about the page).
With the text

Ukraine is seriously considering the possibility of restoring nuclear weapons. This is reported by Bild with reference to a source.
“We have the materials, we have the knowledge. If there is an order, it will only take us a few weeks to get the first bomb,” said a Ukrainian official.
In a conversation with the American presidential candidate Donald Trump (78) a few weeks ago, the Ukrainian [president Zelensky] declared: "Either Ukraine will have nuclear weapons, and then they will be our defense. Or we will have to enter into some kind of alliance. Apart from NATO, we do not know of any effective alliances today."

He also claimed that Trump replied "Your reasoning is fair".
A similar post has also popped up on X.
So is it real, did Ukraine claim its possible for them to make nuclear weapons?

How are we going to verify the quotes from an unnamed official (quoted by BILD) one way or the other? Perhaps there were witnesses to what Zelensky told Trump (which is the other half of the claim), but I'm a bit skeptical.

Your German link points to an article in the Bild newspaper, which is a mainstream newspaper but it's a populist tabloid of mixed reliability.

There is no reason to doubt that Ukrainian officials are indeed considering bringing back nuclear weapons. Whether they have any credible capacity to succeed is a different matter.

If you understand how to design stuff meant to operate in the critical realm (say, a power reactor) you would be insane to not also understand operating in the prompt critical realm (as you absolutely want to ensure that that doesn't happen.)  At that point it's simply a matter of how good a bomb you can build.  But having the materials is quite another matter--why in the world would they have weapons grade materials?  There is little peaceful use of weapons grade materials.

It will take a while before Ukraine can challenge the USSR in a nuclear war, even if they start production today.  I can't see this as anything more than a demand for support of the Budapest Memorandum...Russia promises not to invade Ukraine (fail), Western countries cosign their support to guarantee protection of Ukraine if Russia attacks (VZ probably feels our current support is better than they got for Crimea and Donbas, but not enough)(To be fair, the UKR government wasn't that interested in standing up to them the first two times), and UKR gives up its nuclear capability.  He's just...

...using the Budapest Memorandum as a rhetorical device, like "Why am I the only one living up to its terms?"

You believe right, it is in German. You do have ways to verify, though. More precisely, you can verify what Google Translate says the Bild article says:
https://www-bild-de.translate.goog/politik/ausland-und-internationales/selenskyj-gibt-dem-westen-die-wahl-nato-beitritt-oder-atom-waffe-671102f9e9471210bb6a7dc9?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp
What it says it says Zelensky said is, he did say this and very soon after (and in a different context) added, he did not say it in earnest.

And for what my German is worth, GT is remarkably true to the original, so they may have access to an English, Bild-backed, edition of the article. Note that, in the context of the title, rudern means "to paddle (back)" i. e. to backpedal.

Well, Zelenskyy did not deny saying it, but...

The Ukrainian leader later clarified at a Thursday press conference with NATO Secretary-General Mark Rutte that “we are not building nuclear weapons. What I meant is that today there is no stronger security guarantee for us besides NATO membership.”


Given that Trump often brings up Putin's nuclear weapons, I personally don't find it too unlikely Zelenskyy broached the subject in that company.

Mr Trump is always interested in big league (biggly) stuff and no doubt enticed that mention.
